# Where's the translation for "Couldn't find <Model>" when I raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried setting the following in my en.yml, but it still shows the original translation.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        record_invalid: "%{errors}"
    exceptions:
      not_found: "%{model_name} not found" // I thought this was the one
```

Any idea how to change the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the exception message, it's hard-coded inside Rails

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6f0cda8f8e208143cbd3b39e786521c2e5cddb7a/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L174

Depending on your case you could do something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' do |exception|
    render json: { message: "#{exception.model} not found" }, status: 500
  end
end
```

Comment: That's strange... thanks for the suggestion though! Seems like a plausible solution.